# UINavigationController not appearing?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `Add View` where when you tap on `Category`, the following code is executed

```
- (void)categoryTapped {
    CategoryGroupViewController *categoryGroupViewController = [[CategoryGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryGroupViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:categoryGroupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`CategoryGroupViewController.h` looks like

```
@interface CategoryGroupViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

`CategoryGroupViewController.m` looks like

```
#import "CategoryGroupViewController.h"
#import "Helper.h"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

@interface CategoryGroupViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *categories;
@end

@implementation CategoryGroupViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // (todo) should come from API
        self.categories = @[@"Food & Drink", @"Utilities"];
    }
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"categoryGroup View loaded");
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    self.navigationController.title = @"Pick Category";
}
...
}
```

When I run my application, I see the following in log

```
2014-11-20 21:29:53.589 myapp-ios[30332:70b] categoryGroup View loaded
```

But on Simulator, I see
[image]

Why don't I see `NavigationController`?

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Navigation controller can be completely 'turned off' from there..

Comment: i think u are presenting only the `CategoryGroupViewController` it is not a navigation controller so u want to present a view controller set it to root view controller of navigation controller

Comment: check whether having navigation controller in storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are presenting your `CategoryGroupViewController` it will not show Navigation Bar by default.

You have to set your `CategoryGroupViewController` as `rootViewController` for `UINavigationController` and instead of presenting `CategoryGroupViewController` present newly created `UINavigationController`.

```
- (void)categoryTapped{
    CategoryGroupViewController *categoryGroupVC = [[CategoryGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryGroupViewController"  bundle:nil];      
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: categoryGroupVC]; 
   [self presentViewController:categoryGroupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned above if u want a navigaioncontroller u can set `CategoryGroupViewController` as a root view for a navigation controller and present it for example,

```
- (void)categoryTapped
{
    CategoryGroupViewController *categoryGroupViewController = [[CategoryGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryGroupViewController"  bundle:nil];
    //add this        
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: categoryGroupViewController]; 
   //present the navigation controller which contains root view controller categoryGroupViewController 
   [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <CategoryGroupViewController: 0xb561410>.`

Comment: sorry for delay .. :( i edited the code as i commented u have to present `navController` not  `categoryGroupViewController ` ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a rootViewController before View did load
[alink]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController already as a [navigationController property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationController), so this is redundant:

```
// Remove this property from CategoryGroupViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Structuring the user interface in the way you are attempting is also incorrect, and would result in a circular reference between CategoryGroupViewController and UINavigationController. First you need to modify your `-viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"categoryGroup View loaded");

    // UINavigationController will use this automatically. 
    self.title = @"Pick Category";    
}
```

Then you should change the way you go about preseting the view controller in your original method:

```
- (void)categoryTapped {
    CategoryGroupViewController *categoryGroupViewController = [[CategoryGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryGroupViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categoryGroupViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Finally, the [introduction in the UINavigationController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html) has a great explanation of how the class should be used. Taking a few minutes to read it would help you tremendously in the future.